# How to get data and then convert it into date specific lines via wk?

Tags: awk

I need to convert the first six values into date in the lines of `EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP`

I still haven't understood logic of awk.

File like as follows...

```
  2018     1     2     0     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP 
  Data
  2018     1     2     1     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP 
  Data
  2018     1     2     2     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
  Data
  2018     1     2     3     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
  Data
  2018     1     2     4     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
  Data  
  2018     1     2     5     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
  Data 
  2018     1     2     6     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
  ...
```

I tried

```
awk '/EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP/ {printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' codg0010.18i
```

Output date format should be day, day of the abbreviated month, year hour:minute:second but excluding "EPOCH OF CURRENT"

```
02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
02-Jan-2018 01:00:00
02-Jan-2018 02:00:00
...
```

Comment: I removed the link to the file. The sample above is sufficient.

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: It should be like:
day - day of the abbreviated month - year hour:second:minute.

Comment: How about reading more about `awk` then? It's not that mysterious how it functions.

Comment: please update the question with what the desired output should look like for the sample data you've provided

Comment: @SeanBright Desire output added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with GNU `awk`

```
$ awk '/EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP/{print strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S",mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6))}' file

02-Jan-2018 00:00:00
02-Jan-2018 01:00:00
02-Jan-2018 02:00:00
02-Jan-2018 03:00:00
02-Jan-2018 04:00:00
02-Jan-2018 05:00:00
02-Jan-2018 06:00:00
```